# Standard deviation MPG

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am getting an error column 'mpg' unknown? I am trying to calculate the stdev of the mpg, a computed column

[image]

```
SELECT Date, Vehicle, Quantity as [Ltrs],
    LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date) AS previousmileage,
    OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date) as [Miles],
    (OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date)) / (Quantity/4.544) as [MPG],
    case when (OdoReadingMiles-LAG(OdoReadingMiles, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Vehicle ORDER BY Date)) / (Quantity/4.544) not between 2 and 10
        then 1 else 0 end as [Anomaly],
    stdev(MPG)
FROM [Fleet].[DwhTriscanChargeouts]
where vehicle='DE63VAM'
order by 2, 1
```

Comment: The MPG column isn't available in the same select list. Use a subquery, or re-calculate MPG.

Comment: @ammarWahid . . . `stdev()` is an *aggregation* function.  It is unclear what you want the results to look like.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're getting this error is that you're trying to calculate STD (MPG)  before the actual value is calculated (possibly).

I suggest you use an inner query calculating the column, then calculating the STD. Inner queries are calculated before upper select clause, which is calculated last in the query.

Don't forget using `GROUP BY` clause since STD is an aggregation function.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT columns are computed in unknown order, so you can not use computed column in same SELECT statement. You can use CTE or subquery.